# Unable to run apt-get update openssl on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, dpkg, nginx

I am trying to run sudo apt-get update openssl on Ubuntu Server 12.04, however when I do, I get the following error:

```
Starting nginx: invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing nginx-extras (--configure)
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
  nginx-extras
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: That error simply means that the `postinst` script of the `nginx-extras` package failed to execute.  You can try to diagnose the problem by doing the following:
`sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-extras.postinst --configure`

Which runs the `postinst` script manually and should give you a bit more output.

It actually looks like `nginx` fails to start, so that may be a good place to start debugging (is it already running?).

Comment: I will give the command a try and see what I get back. According to the services status, nginx is running. However when I try to access the site, it is currently inaccessible.

Comment: Try stopping it (`sudo service nginx stop`) and then re-running `apt-get update openssl`.  Also, see what `/var/log/syslog` has regarding starting/stopping of nginx.

Comment: @Piotrek - I ran your command and it wouldn't accept the --configure value.

Comment: @Piotrek - I did however stop the service and get the openssl to install. Problem is that the site is still not available.

Comment: that looks like an nginx config problem.  Verify the firewall allows access to the port which is configured to be used by nginx.  You can also run `sudo netstat -tupan | grep nginx` to see which ports nginx is actively using.

Comment: I was a little jumpy on this issue. It is working now. Thank you very much. Guess my problem was trying to do the update while nginx was running.